# communicate to flash media server from browser not with swf

Tags: c#, javascript, flash, media

Cen i communicate to FMS from browser not with swf.
For example - by javascript from user side or by C# from IIS server side.

I need to built a live chat application where the swf only get the live stream and show it to the user
but all the other logic code that communicate to FMS will be not in the swf and not in some *.exe file.

I need this because this live chat appliction will have to work on apple ipad and iphone
soon when FMS will be able to stream to those devices and i will have to abandon the swf anyway.

big thanks for your help

cheinan

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use javascript, in particular [xmlhttprequest](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_http.asp) .

its pretty simple, in a javascript just put something along the lines of :

```
function examplefunction() {
var url = example.com
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { req = new XMLHttpRequest(); } 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) { req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
  if (req != null) {

req.open("POST", url, false);
    req.send("test");
}
if(req.responseText == "Hello") { ...etc....
```

Comment: you totally did not understand my question... you gave a simple AJAX javascript example from user side.   but i am asking here about flash media server... how the AJAX from user side communicate with flash media server?

Comment: oh i understand now, well im not sure how FMS works since i never used one, but which scripting language are you running on the server? Like for example if in my javascript i make a call to example.com/examplescript.pl then in my perl script i would have something like ...
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') { read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
Therefore this script on the server takes in POST calls, reads the standard input and puts the data into the buffer. Then you do whatever you want with it. This can be done in php and any other scripting language i only know Perl sorry